# Can the Mono Virtual Machine Be Shared Accross Processes?

Tags: c#, mono

If I want to run two or more console applications under mono on Linux, will I incur the overhead of the Mono virtual machine for each process or will parts of the virtual machine be reused across processes? If this is not the case, is there a way to share parts of the memory used by the mono virtual machines?

I would like to achieve the following: Let's assume that the mono virtual machine requires 100MB when many assemblies of the standard library are loaded by an application. The specifics of Application A make it use an extra 50Mb of RAM (so the total RAM used by process A is 150Mb) and the specifics of Application B make it us an extra 120Mb of RAM (so the total RAM used by process B is 220Mb).

If the way Mono works, two independent Mono Virtual Machines will be spawned, then I'll be using 370Mb of RAM. However, if the memory of things such as the base library is shared between virtual machines, then I'd only be using 100 + 50 + 120 = 270Mb of RAM.

The thing is, I may be in a situation where I run dozens or hundreds of relatively small applications, and I'm concerned that the memory reserved by each mono virtual machine would massively degrade the memory footprint of the deployment while the RAM requirements of each individual application wouldn't actually be that large. I am talking about console applications (web services).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, **it depends**. ;-)

1. **Linux will always share the read-only segments** of selfsame executables running multiple times. I.e. the executable code and constant data of the VM exists only once in memory while the mutable data is not shared.
2. But there is one thing to know. Since Mono is a Just in Time Compiler it will translate the IL language to native code of your platform. Here your problem begins. **The translated code is generated at runtime and resides in non read-only memory segments.** The kernel no longer knows about this redundancy and so the memory taken for the mono class libraries will not be shared among Mono VMs running at the same host.
   (In fact the memory pages will not exactly match anyway because the different VMs might run code paths slightly different, e.g. load the classes of the runtime in a different order or something like that.)
3. Things would be easy if this were the end of the story but it isn't. There is another Mono feature: **AOT (Ahead of Time Compilation)**.
   In this case the ode is not compiled to machine language by the JIT at run time. Instead the has been precompiled earlier. In this case the precompiled code is *read-only* from the VMs instances point of view. Now the kernel will again *share* the precompiled code as constant data.
   See [AOT: Increased Memory Sharing](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/#increased-memory-sharing)
4. But this is still not the end of the story. **The AOT compiler** does support all features of Mono, it **has limitations**. It is not able to handle all program patterns. So *some* runtime classes are not shared. Details depend on the Mono version as well as on your platform.
   See [Ahead of Time Compilation (AOT)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/aot/) for more details.

So the answer is not that easy. Depending on the Mono version and on whether your referenced libraries include precompiled code for your platform more or less memory is shared among concurrently running VMs.

In practice it will be something in between of your pessimistic assumption and your optimistic assumption. You can be pretty sure that some data segments of the VM cannot be shared even if AOT does a really good job. E.g. internal variables and class instances like reflection classes will *not* be shared.
AOT only covers the IL code but not expressions and objects that only depend on design time constants like C++ `constexpr` does.

I have no idea how it scales in *your* particular use case. But you are talking about hundreds of *relatively small* applications. A small application will most likely not have 100 MB of runtime overhead. At least I would not call this "small application" anymore.

---

But one further suggestion: **Do not start hundreds of parallel processes.** Even if the Mono VMs does a good job with respect to memory sharing it is an excessive use of system resources. Use a queue instead that delegates the tasks to a *limited* number of processes, or rethink your concept in some other way. It is very likely that run into non-linear scalability and a bad worst case performance otherwise.